# yasnippet, "Wrong number of arguments" when in X11 window

Tags: yasnippet

Using `yasnippet`, whenever I use the `yas-expand` function to expand a snippet, the result depends on whether the emacs session is in an X window or not.  If I am in an in-terminal session of emacs, then the snippet is correctly expanded.  If I am in an X window, on the other hand, I get an error message `call-interactively: Wrong number of arguments: (2 . 2), 0`.

Have others encountered this problem, and is there a solution to it?

I am using yasnippet, with the latest version 20170127.2128 installed from melpa, using emacs 24.4.1 installed from the `emacs24` package on Debian 8 (Jessie).

Edit: With `toggle-debug-on-error`

`Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (2 . 2) 0)
  py-indent-region()
  call-interactively(py-indent-region nil nil)
  command-execute(py-indent-region)`

It looks like I was entirely mistaken about which function was being run.  I have `yas-expand` bound to `C-c <tab>`, but something else in my configuration overwrote that binding.

Comment: Can you `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and post the backtrace?

Comment: Added, and it looks like I was entirely mistaken about the source of the error.  Thank you for the suggestion, as I didn't know how to get a backtrace in elisp.